Kotlin version error in Flutter project: Module compiled with incompatible Kotlin version
I recently revisited a Flutter project that I hadn't touched in over 2 years. After opening it and updating the Gradle and Kotlin versions, I encountered an issue when trying to build the APK or run the app in release mode using the commands flutter build apk or flutter run --release. The error message states: "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0". Strangely, the app works fine in debug and profile modes.
I've attempted the following approaches to resolve the issue:

Deleted Gradle cache
Upgraded to the latest Kotlin version (1.9.23)
Downgraded Kotlin version to 1.6.0
flutter clean & flutter pub get


However, none of these solutions have helped. Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this Kotlin version compatibility issue?
Here are relevant snippets from my project's build.gradle and gradle.properties files:
build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

gradle.properties:
#Tue Apr 09 12:00:26 IST 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

I've also referred to several Stack Overflow posts related to this issue, but haven't found a solution yet:

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3

error log
e: other files/my-app/arcore_flutter_plugin/.transforms/f39fb4032ea66347d24faef5e111f4d0/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/arcore_flutter_plugin_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: other files/my-app/flutter_email_sender/.transforms/e41ad79431d4394b70406c2bf6b2df42/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/flutter_email_sender_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: other files/my-app/wakelock/.transforms/1113f73603aa5f492fef390312763387/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/wakelock_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: other files/my-app/device_info_plus/.transforms/69b198a981f53349112f410cc8d4b737/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/device_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: other files/my-app/hmssdk_flutter/.transforms/328da43348617b35dfa4fe66be05c595/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/hmssdk_flutter_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f2b1c7a43f771f864943924aeee52fb0/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-android/1.7.2/55dc9f2e0c18ef8aa98367599a22d434790848b8/kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c4ca1b3e7d97b2fb42620d397b1e4003/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/426f3f66e1c58b3bd2e92630e5014b8a/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.7.2/27cb5db69aeef59d8cc2a2cc2be4200f26091e72/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/1.7.2/d8b01823c681c6cfdba6ef76f62d87a2b5d88066/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services-1.7.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4b907693550fdef6661f7bcae153126c/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.13.0-alpha01/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/269aef7382a10ec574d3e2a34a3e535b/transformed/core-1.13.0-alpha01/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/bhara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.


Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
